# Powershell | Custom parameter/attribute of .jpg

Tags: powershell, attributes, jpeg

Dear stackoverflowers,

I have a problem with some files. I would like to search for a specific attribute value of a .jpg file. Specifically the "commentary" field.

I tried it like that:

```
(Get-ChildItem -file C:\picture.jpg | Select-Object -Property *).attributes
```

All I receive is this:

```
Archive
```

Well, that does not help me.
I would like to know, what is in this "Archive". There (or maybe somewhere else?) must be those informations I seek.

```
(Get-ChildItem -file C:\picture.jpg | Select-Object -Property *)
Attributes        : Archive
```

Doesn't give me any relevant information besides the one, which I already got.

I guess I should be able to get the needed information with this powershell pack:
[Technet - EXIF](http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/9f1da16f-9f78-4808-bf87-b676de631bad/how-can-i-get-properties-from-the-details-tab-of-a-jpg-file?forum=ITCG)
But isn't there any way to easily access this data, with the on-board powershell? (I would like to use it on many different computers)

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try something like this:

```
function MakeString
{
  $s=""
    for ($i=0 ; $i -le $args[0].value.length; $i ++) 
    {
        if ( [int][char]$args[0].value[$i] -ne 0 )
        {
        $s = $s + [char]$args[0].value[$i] 
        }
    }    

   $s
}

[void][reflection.assembly]::loadfile( "C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v2.0.50727\System.Drawing.dll")

$foo=New-Object -TypeName system.drawing.bitmap -ArgumentList "c:\test_image_with_exif_comment_populated.jpg"

makestring $foo.GetPropertyItem(37510) #37510 is the property ID for exif comment use 40092 for property XPComment
```

**remember that if the property comment is not populated the command** `$foo.GetPropertyItem(37510)` **return an error!**

or to avoid the error use this function:

```
    function get-jpgcomment ( [string]$path )
    {
    [void][reflection.assembly]::loadfile( "C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v2.0.50727\System.Drawing.dll")
    $foo=New-Object -TypeName system.drawing.bitmap -ArgumentList $path #"c:\Users\baric\Pictures\IMG\b.jpg"

    try
    {
        $a = $foo.GetPropertyItem(37510)
        -join ($a.value | % { if ([int][char]$_ -ne 0) {[char]$_} })    
    }

    catch
    {}
}
```

call it like this:

```
get-jpgcomment c:\myimage.jpg
```

it return `$null` if the property comment is not populated.

Comment: Wow! This is great. It works! It was "40092" for me. But you solved my problem, Sir! Thank you very much. Even though I have absolutely no idea how this works.

Comment: @XXInvidiaXX Glad to help! Try read here to understand how it works: http://blogs.technet.com/b/jamesone/archive/2007/07/13/exploring-photographic-exif-data-using-powershell-of-course.aspx

Comment: @XXInvidiaXX I've edited my answer changing something in the last  function just to be more 'powershelling'...

Comment: Makes it easier to understand for me! thank you. I will try to work through it and experiment a bit.

Comment: One last question: How do I release the .jpg file from the Powershell session?

Comment: @XXInvidiaXX with 2 commands: `$foo.Dispose(); remove-variable foo;` the second one  is not mandatory...